# Flash banner links on domainA, but not working on domainB

Tags: hyperlink, flash

I'd like to know that, why my flash banner not working? There's a company, who wants to advertise on my site, with her own flash banner, but when I've inserted it into my site, it doesn't link, but if I open it in a new window(only the SWF file), it works perfectly.
Please help me, becouse I don't know why is it so buggy.

The link for SWF file: http://www.szolnokinaplo.hu/feltoltes/banner/alla.swf

The site, where i'd like to insert(the upper one): http://szolnokinaplo.hu/2012/05/11/kevesebb-virag-a-viragos-varosban/

Thanks for your help. :)

Yours, 
Barnabás

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't edit de .fla file maybe you can put the  tag in the html file with an absolute root :)

Comment: I have the .FLA file, becouse I've asked for it, but what shell i do, to make it work? :)

Comment: It works perfectly, after i've changed it to absolute root, thank you very much; what a strange bug :D